# Single inotify read makes infinite loop

Tags: inotify

As of title.
The program will wait for the first event, and then go into an infinite loop - why doesn't it just process one event at a time?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int id, wd;
    int a;
    struct inotify_event e;

    id = inotify_init ();
    wd = inotify_add_watch (id, "/home/andrea/Downloads", IN_CREATE);
    puts ("waiting...");
    while (read (id, &e, sizeof (struct inotify_event)))
      {
          printf ("created %s\n", e.name);
          puts ("waiting...");
      }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, maybe it's obvious, but my questions is: why doesn't it just process one event at a time?

Comment: No one answered. Well, I found out that the code manages the struct (which has a variable-length array at the end) in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the events reported by inotify aren't of the size inotify_event, since there is an additional name reported as well.  Use ioctl with FIONREAD to get the amount of bytes available for reading.

```
int avail;
ioctl(id, FIONREAD, &avail);
```

Secondly, you used blocking I/O.  If you instead use inotify_init1(O_NONBLOCK) to initialise inotify, read() will immediately return and set errno to EAGAIN if no data is available.  Of course, this is optional if you first used FIONREAD to check if there is data available in the first place.